# Merging small polygons with the biggest adjacent ones

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I want to merge the RED polygons with the YELLOW polygons.
But i want to merge the one red polygon with the adjancent polygon with yellow one. This polygons are in one Feature class but classified in atributes.
I am trying many methods but it doesnt work or i dont know how to do.

[image: here it is the image of my polygons]

Comment: Are you using QGIS or ArcGIS? (you have both tags) Do you have both available and would take a solution in either? If you have ArcGIS what license level do you have available?

Comment: I use only Arcgis i know it better sorry for taggs, I dont know how to look licence level sorry?

Comment: Help::About Arcmap... look at the 2nd line where it says License Type: if you can access eliminate your license level *must* be advanced. This is important information when offering help with ArcGIS as the available tools are governed by the license type.

Comment: Could you put some sample data for downloading?

Comment: i just can send in email because i cant post here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Eliminate](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/eliminate.htm) tool to accomplish this. It does exactly this: "Eliminates polygons by merging them with neighboring polygons that have the largest area or the longest shared border. "

Comment: I tried the eliminate field but this merges only the small with small polygons that are adjencent. But it doesn merge with the neighbour with yellow polygon.                    Do you know how use or tu write any extensions at the eliminate .

Comment: I would suggest that you probably have a selection (or definition query), which is why you're only merging red polygons. Before using Eliminate you might want to start with Polygon to Line (with IDs) then join by left and right, select the ones that are red on one side (you might need to do some work here to find and select only the largest adjacent for each red polygon) and remove these lines then use the line feature class in the eliminate tool to avoid merging the big polygons.

Comment: could you help me better Dear. i did polygon to line in toolbox and created lines but not one polygon to 1 line but created 2 or 3 lines. can you help in email if i send you shape f