# Merging adjoining polygons by rule

Tags: qgis, r, topology

I have a huge vector layer coming from an aerial image classification, containing lots of small polygons.
I’m willing to clean it a bit (i.e. "removing" polygons < 25 sq. metres) but I didn’t find any tool related to a rule-based merge capable of merging adjoining polygons according to the longest shared border or biggest neighbouring area.

I already found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264622/merging-small-polygons-with-the-biggest-adjacent-ones) question, but it was solved using ArcGIS, while I'm looking for alternatives in R or QGIS.

Comment: If you want to merge polygons based on a rule, it would be rather helpful if you shared said rule.

Comment: "merging adjoining polygons according to longest shared border or biggest neighbouring area"

Comment: How is the "or" defined? When do you use which?

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/336133/8104. What are the features (e.g. trees, cars, houses, etc..)? Are you able to dissolve the features to simplify the geometry? What does the intended output look like? Please edit your post with these details.

Answer (score 1):

After digging quite a bit, it seems I was looking around using the wrong terms. The tool `Eliminate selected polygons`in QGIS (see second comment [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326705/automatically-fill-gaps-and-merge-freshly-generated-polygons-with-the-longest-ad)) allows what I have to do.
Nevertheless, solutions in R are still appreciated.